# Run SQL script on JDBC connection, minimal approach

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

Long story short: I want to run a SQL script on an HSQLDB database.

I want to follow a minimalistic approach, which means:

- *Absolutely no manual parsing of SQL*
- No additional dependencies except for general Utilities. I make the distinction here because, for example I refuse to pull in Ibatis or Hibernate which are larger scope frameworks, but I will accept an apache commons or guava type utils library.
- The library MUST BE AVAILABLE ON MAVEN. No small-time pet-project stuff.
- (EDIT 12/5/15) Must have the ability to execute SQL file from classpath.

To give you some context:

```
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb", "sa", "");
        // Run script here
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load database", e);
    }
```

A one-liner would be great. Something like:

```
    FancyUtils.runScript(connection, new File("myFile.sql"));
```

I did find [org.hsqldb.persist.ScriptRunner](https://fossies.org/dox/hsqldb-2.3.3/classorg_1_1hsqldb_1_1persist_1_1ScriptRunner.html) but it takes a Database object as an argument and I can't seem to figure out how to get an instance. Also, I don't like the description of "Restores the state of a Database", so does that mean my database will be cleared first? That's definitely not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried using the `SqlFile` object in [SqlTool](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html) and it worked for me. The Maven dependency I used was

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqltool</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The SQL script file I wanted to execute was "C:/Users/Public/test/hsqldbCommands.sql":

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (id, textcol) VALUES (2, 'stuff');
INSERT INTO table1 (id, textcol) VALUES (3, 'more stuff');
```

and my Java test code was

```java
package hsqldbMaven;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlFile;

public class HsqldbMavenMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connUrl = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/Public/test/hsqldb/personal";
        String username = "SA";
        String password = "";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl, username, password)) {
            // clear out previous test data
            try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
                st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID > 1");
            }

            System.out.println("Before:");
            dumpTable(conn);

            // execute the commands in the .sql file
            SqlFile sf = new SqlFile(new File("C:/Users/Public/test/hsqldbCommands.sql"));
            sf.setConnection(conn);
            sf.execute();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("After:");
            dumpTable(conn);

            try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
                st.execute("SHUTDOWN");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    private static void dumpTable(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        try (
                Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT id, textcol FROM table1")) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.printf("%d - %s%n", rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("textcol"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

producing

```
Before:
1 - Hello world!

After:
1 - Hello world!
2 - stuff
3 - more stuff
```

**Edit: 2018-08-26**

If you want to bundle your SQL script file into the project as a resource then see the example in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685234/2144390).

Note also that this approach is not restricted to HSQLDB databases. It can be used for other databases as well (e.g., MySQL, SQL Server).

Comment: I don't like the fact that this is essentially using a CLI as a utils API, but it does solve the problem and really seems to be the best solution overall. I ended up making lists of sql statements in Java instead of making the scripts, because I was rushed. But I trust the answer works.

Comment: Finally got around to using it, but there is a major problem - this solution cannot run a file from the classpath, so I cannot bundle my schema with the source code. This is a deal-breaker for me.

Comment: It's dangerous to assume a java process will have access to a filesystem. Best to avoid this dependency if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This uses the SqlTool library, but reads the script directly from the classpath by using the `SqlFile` class:

```
try(InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/script.sql")) {
    SqlFile sqlFile = new SqlFile(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), "init", System.out, "UTF-8", false, new File("."));
    sqlFile.setConnection(connection);
    sqlFile.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though iBatis was mentioned by the OP as a non-requirement, I still want to recommend MyBatis - the iBatis fork by the original creators.

The core library (`org.mybatis:mybatis`) requires no dependencies (all of its dependencies are optional) and while larger than HSQLDB SqlTool, at 1.7MB binary it is not horribly big for most uses and is continuously maintained (the last release, 3.5, was last month as of this writing).

You can initialize `ScriptRunner` with a JDBC `Connection`, then call `runScript(new InputStreamReader(sqlinputst, Standard chartered.UTF_8))` to run whatever SQL script you can get an input steam of.

Comment: To my knowledge, Mybatis doesn't allow you to simply run a sql script from the classpath. Instead you would need to put the sql into a properly-formatted xml file and setup boilerplate code for reading the xml.

Comment: I added script running instructions to the answer.