# How to load a SQL file (stored in the source folder of my Java project) into MySQL from a Java Application?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, netbeans6.5

I want to load an SQL file (which is stored in the source folder of my NetBeans Java Project) into MySQL from my Java Application during runtime. How can I do this?

The SQL file is 15.15 MB in size and I am wondering whether I can copy into a String or not? Or if I anyhow manage to copy it to a String (though it may throw out of memory error), how to execute multiple commands in one go (because the SQL file contains many commands).

I want to do it without using any additional tools. Just using pre-existing libraries and classes in java (that are bundled with JDK).

Comment: If the file is made up of separate smaller SQL commands, you should read each command in at a time.  Theoretically you can load a 15Mb String, but you'll probably run out of memory.

Comment: You could write a background service to use the `mysqlimport` command to load the file in one go, that will do the file splitting and running for you.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the solution but I don't know how to do so. I am just a fresher to java programming. I'll be happy if you tell me how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you can use the flyway lib. It is used to execute flyway migrations via java or sql files. It might be a bit too much for your goal but I suggets to have a look at https://flywaydb.org.

Comment: @Anton Thanks. I will look up the website...

Comment: @VaibhavAgrawal you are welcome :-)

Comment: A similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33336063/2144390) has an answer that uses [SqlTool](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html) to accomplish what you describe.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks. I found it working.

Comment: Good to hear. Perhaps you might consider posting an answer to let others know what ultimately worked for you.

Comment: @GordThompson Hey, Sorry but the answer you have referenced, just works with HSQL and not with MySQL. SQLTool too works with just HSQL. Not Working!!!

Comment: *"SQLTool too works with just HSQL"* - Not true. If you look at the sample configuration file ("RC file") [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#sqltool_auth-sect) you will see examples for Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, and Derby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found that it is probably impossible to do it yet without adding additional tools and libraries.**

We can do it by splitting the SQL file into smaller SQL files, each containing just one SQL command and then initiating a loop to execute all those files at once. I'd tried it and it works. It certainly does.

The following is the code I used to do that :

```
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.sql.* ;
import java.io.* ;

public class LoadSQLFile {
    public static void main(string args[ ]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "We need your MySQL Password to run the application. Please enter it here.", " MySQL Password ?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) ;
                    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver") ;
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyDB", "root", password) ;
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                    int i = 0 ;
                    for(i=1;i<=16;i++) {
                        FileReader fr = new FileReader("src//sql_files//BCK"+i+".sql") ;
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr) ;
                        stmt.execute(br.readLine()) ;
                    }
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Records Successfully Inserted into database !", "Success !", 1) ;
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) ;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I was to execute SQL files stored in my project's source folder inside a package named "sql_files". The names of the files are - BCK1.sql, BCK2.sql, ...., BCK16.sql. Each file contained just one SQL file in just first line. It worked just fine for me.

*I used the MySQL JDBC Driver for this.*

Comment: is this okay if the file of SQL is quite big?

Comment: Yeah, because it uses readLine(), it'll read only one line at a time. So, even if the SQL file is big, there won't be any problems.

Comment: i'm afraid if the content of the blob or something related to it will have non-single-line.... so it will ends up failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think [ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html#executeSqlScript-java.sql.Connection-org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource-) can help you.

Comment: No. But not Sure. I think it'll not work because its connection can't be loaded for SQL execution to MySQL contained in the source folders of the Project.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
public static String readFileAsString(Class clazz, String filePath) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = clazz.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not found: " + filePath);
    }
    return IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
}

public static final Path SQL_QUERY_FILE_PATH = Paths.get("SqlFolder", "productQuery.sql");

String sqlQuery = FileResourceUtil.readFileAsString(getClass(), SQL_QUERY_FILE_PATH.toString());
```

Comment: feel free to code review or edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is example, This will print 3 statements.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        var sql = "select;insert(';')\n sdfsd;"
                + "update";

        List<String> stmt = new ArrayList<>();

        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.splitSqlScript(sql, ";", stmt);

        stmt.forEach(e -> log.info(e));
    }
```