# How to execute a long MySQL script in Java without adding external libs?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, string, jdbc

I'm using JDBC MySqlDataSource class to handle a database for my app. I'm trying to make a method that formats the database for app's use - creates tables and constraints. Basically it's a script generated from phpMyAdmin export option. I've made a class called DatabaseTemplate with a static String containing the script and then I use it in my formatDatabase method.

```
public void formatDatabase() {
        try {
            sql.executeUpdate(DatabaseTemplate.GetScript());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It makes an SQL exception "Syntax not correct". My script string looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `arenas` (
  `arena_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_polish_ci;
CREATE TABLE `contestants` (
  `contestant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `contact_info` text COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `additional_info` text COLLATE utf16_polish_ci,
  `team_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_polish_ci;
CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sideA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sideB` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sideA_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sideB_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `tournament` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_polish_ci;
CREATE TABLE `system_users` (
  `sys_usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(20) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `pw_hash` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `permissions` varchar(5) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_polish_ci;
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `where_from` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `leader_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_polish_ci;
CREATE TABLE `tournaments` (
  `tournament_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('solo','team') COLLATE utf16_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `arena_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `operator` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `additional_info` text COLLATE utf16_polish_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_polish_ci;
ALTER TABLE `arenas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`arena_id`);
ALTER TABLE `contestants`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`contestant_id`),
  ADD KEY `team_id` (`team_id`);
ALTER TABLE `matches`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`),
  ADD KEY `sideA` (`sideA`),
  ADD KEY `sideB` (`sideB`),
  ADD KEY `tournament` (`tournament`);
ALTER TABLE `system_users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sys_usr_id`);
ALTER TABLE `teams`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`team_id`),
  ADD KEY `leader_id` (`leader_id`);
ALTER TABLE `tournaments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tournament_id`),
  ADD KEY `arena_id` (`arena_id`),
  ADD KEY `operator` (`operator`);
ALTER TABLE `contestants`
  MODIFY `contestant_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `contestants`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contestants_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `teams` (`team_id`);
ALTER TABLE `matches`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `matches_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sideA`) REFERENCES `teams` (`team_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `matches_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sideB`) REFERENCES `teams` (`team_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `matches_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`tournament`) REFERENCES `tournaments` (`tournament_id`);
ALTER TABLE `teams`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `teams_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`leader_id`) REFERENCES `contestants` (`contestant_id`);

ALTER TABLE `tournaments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tournaments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`arena_id`) REFERENCES `arenas` (`arena_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tournaments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`operator`) REFERENCES `system_users` (`sys_usr_id`);
```

I'm guessing it's because of how String in java uses \n. I tried removing it, changing it to \r\n, it's still the same exception. How do I format this script so that it executes properly?

Comment: The ``\n`` will not cause "Syntax not correct" exception. You get that exception because you messed up the actual SQL statement, but since you didn't show the full SQL, we can't help you figure out where you did it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It might be good to read the J[ava documentation on issuing SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) queries as it seems you are using the wrong method in your code.

If you are curious about the difference between [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) (Data Definition Language) and [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) (Data Manipulation Language), there are valuable articles on them on Wikipedia.

You might find it easier to place the sql in a dedicated file `setup.sql` and then load the file when needed and execute the sql from the file. If your code contains more than one SQL statement, you could store each in a separate file.

That way your SQL query will:

1. actually be readable to a human and
2. there will be no issues with multi-line strings in Java.

Comment: How do I read the sql file tho? All I find is by using some external libs.

Comment: This seems to be matching your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759298/how-to-load-a-sql-file-stored-in-the-source-folder-of-my-java-project-into-mys

Comment: @shak See [read complete file without using loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14169729/5221149): `String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: @Andreas I still get "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `contestants` (
  `contestant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varc' at line 6"

Comment: @shak And how are we supposed to help you with that without knowing the full SQL statement?

Comment: I have added the full SQL script to main post.