# Executing batch of DDL statements in one query java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a query which batch of sql commands in one string,

```
 String SQLQuery =

"CREATE VOLATILE TABLE v1;
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE v2;

INSERT INTO v1;
//do stuff
INSERT INTO v2;
//do stuff
UPDATE xx;
//do stuff

DROP TABLE v1;
DROP TABLE v2;"
```

I tried to execute them with executeUpdate(), executeBatch() both of them fails with java jdbc client, which works in Teradata client.

```
 Error mesg:
 [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.35] [Error 3576] [SQLState 25000] Data definition not valid unless solitary.
```

Java code:

```
    PreparedStatement stmt10 = null;
    try {

        stmt10 = conn.prepareStatement(SQLQuery);
        //stmt10.executeUpdate();
        stmt10.executeBatch();
        //conn.commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (stmt10 != null) {
            stmt10.close();
        }
    }
```

how can i do this?

Comment: `executeBatch` is to use with `addBatch` to send a batch of command to execute at once. This shoud be a simple `Statement` with an `execute` I thing

Comment: @AxelH I tried also just execute(), which fails with same error

Comment: You could probably use a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33358713/2144390), which uses [SqlTool](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html) to parse and execute a file of SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

In teradata you cannot execute DDL statements together. It's not a problem with the JDBC or the java code - just the way you want to use teradata. That is what that error is basically saying:

http://teradataerror.com/3576-Data-definition-not-valid-unless-solitary.html

So you need to send the separate the DDL statements in separate transactions with a separate requests. If it was multiple updates and selects it would work just fine but create table cannot be executed like that.

I believe it is due to the fact that any DDL request MUST be commited before actually happening. And if you use it like that it is not. I think it is actually OK to have DDL in a multiple commands query if it is only one and it is the last statement .

Comment: But I executed those multiple statements in Teradata clients like Teradata Admin, Assistant. Which worked fine, only via jdbc multiple DDL statements are not executable

Comment: maybe the client is sending them one by one? I don't have teradata right now to test how exactly does it work