# Can I run a "source" command (SQL script) from a JDBC connection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm writing an application that has a data access layer to abstract the underlying connections to SQLITE3 or MySQL databases.

Thanks to some help here yesterday I was shown how to use a process builder to run a command line import into the SQLITE3 DB using output redirection.

Now I am trying to create the same database but in MySQL by importing a dump file. The load works fine from the command line client. I just tell it to source the file and the DB is created successfully.

However I am trying to do this through code at runtime and my method for executing a SQL statement fails to execute the source command.

I suspect that this is because "source" is not SQL but I don't know what else to use to try and run it.

My error message is:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source /tmp/ISMCoreActionPack_mysql.sql' at line 1
```

The failing command string:

```
source /tmp/ISMCoreActionPack_mysql.sql;
```

My method is:

```
public Boolean executeSqlStatement(String sql)  {
    Boolean rc = false;
    try {
      Connection connection = getConnection();
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      rc = statement.execute(sql);
      connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
      System.exit(1);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run 'source' command, because it's not supported by JDBC driver, only MySQL.

My advice to you the following. Write some parser, which reads queries from a file, and executes them using JDBC statements.

Comment: Yes, I think I might have to. Although loading form a dump seems like a blindingly obvious way to create databases. Why on earth wasn't this added to the driver?

Answer (score 0):

`source` is not part of MySQL's dialect of SQL; it is a MySQL shell command. Still, you shouldn't need to write your own parser. You could use something like [SqlTool](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33358713/2144390).